# Python TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects

Tags: python, file-io

```
f = open("open","rw")
w = open("write","w")

def fonk():
    c = ""
    a = f.readline().decode('utf-8')
    for line in f:
        b = line.decode('utf-8')
        splitted = line.split()     
        w.write("'"+splitted[4:]+"'"+",")

fonk()
```

I want to read words of file called "open" and write it to another file called "write". I can write the 4th character but I want to write 4 and more in this case I get the error on the title. What should I do?

Comment: `"'"` string, `splitted[4:]` list. try `w.write("'"+''.join(splitted[4:])+"'"+",")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
w.write("'"+''.join(splitted[4:])+"'"+",")
```

Because you are trying string and list concatanation. This is not allowed.